# Not able to insert object type into table on Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, object, types, oracle11g

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CURSOR AS OBJECT(
    code varchar2(20),
    className varchar2(30),
    teach1 Teacher,
    maximumPupils number,
    maximumHours number,

    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION cursor(code varchar2, className varchar2, passport Teacher, maximumPupils number, maximumHours number) RETURN SELF AS RESULT


 )NOT FINAL;



CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CURSOR
AS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION cursor(code varchar2, className varchar2, passport Teacher, maximumPupils number, maximumHours number) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
IS
BEGIN 
    SELF.code := code;
    SELF.className := className;
    SELF.passport:=passport;
    SELF.maximumPupils := maximumPupils;
    SELF.maximumHours := maximumHours;


END;


------------------------

CREATE TABLE SubjectClass OF Cursor;


-----------------------------------------


BEGIN
    insert into SubjectClass values(1,'Class 1','43345678F',30,55);


END;
```

I have tried all the following, (that includes the use of a full constructor reference) only with the atribute .passport of the Teacher object which I am willing to insert or reference the other table where it exists (this passport number previously exists in another object type table called Teachers):

INSERT INTO SubjectClass VALUES('1','Class 1', Teacher.passport('12345678A'),20,25);

INSERT INTO SubjectClass values(1,'Class 1','43345678F',30,55);

Please help, I have a test soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following TYPEs:

```
create or replace type teacher as object (
  passport  varchar2( 32 )
, something varchar2( 64 )
, another   varchar2( 64 )
)
/

create or replace type cursor_ as object (
  code varchar2(20)
, className varchar2(30)
, teacher_ teacher
, maximumPupils number
, maximumHours number
, constructor function cursor_ (
    code varchar2
  , className varchar2
  , teacher_ teacher
  , maximumPupils number
  , maximumHours number
  ) return self as result
) not final 
/
```

The code for TYPE BODY of cursor_ could look something like ...

```
create or replace type body cursor_
as
  constructor function cursor_ (
    code varchar2
  , className varchar2
  , teacher_ teacher
  , maximumPupils number
  , maximumHours number
  ) return self as result
  as
  begin
    self.code := code ;
    self.className := className ;
    self.teacher_ := teacher_ ;
    self.maximumPupils := maximumPupils ;
    self.maximumHours := maximumHours ; 
    return ;
  end; 
end;
/
```

Notice that the TYPE BODY has 2 "end;" lines.  Your original type body code compiles with errors due to the fact that one "end" is missing.

Now you can create a table for cursor_ objects, and insert some test data:

```
create table subjectclass of cursor_ ;

begin
  insert into subjectclass values (
    new cursor_ ( 1, 'class1', new teacher( 'AA1100BB', 'something1', 'another1' ), 100, 16 ) 
  );
  insert into subjectclass values (
    new cursor_ ( 2, 'class2', new teacher( 'BB2211CC', 'something2', 'another2' ), 120, 25 ) 
  );
end ;
/
```

Example query for the subjectclass table:

```
 select 
  S.code
, S.classname
, S.teacher_.passport  as T_PP
, S.teacher_.something as T_ST
, S.teacher_.another   as T_AO
, S.maximumpupils as max_p
, S.maximumhours  as max_h
from subjectclass S ;

-- result
CODE  CLASSNAME  T_PP      T_ST        T_AO      MAX_P  MAX_H  
1     class1     AA1100BB  something1  another1  100    16     
2     class2     BB2211CC  something2  another2  120    25
```

See dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6934302016f4da433e14921dc7316c7).

Comment: Thanks! What if the Teacher object had more attributes? In my case I have several and just one primary key. When trying to instantiate doing this directly from BEGIN/END statement: new cursor_ ( 1, 'class1', new teacher( 'AA1100BB','param1','param2' ), 100, 16 ) I gain this: "PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'teacher' match this call"

Comment: "More attributes" should not pose any problems - see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Appreciated! +1 for you! :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  Best of luck.